# send SMTP mail the client and server cannot communicate because they do not possess a common algorithm smtp

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtpclient

I am trying generate email using SMTP but i dont want to add creadentials my code. At my local PC is working fine but on server it is giving me error

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(SmtpServer_con);
mail.From = new MailAddress(MailFrom);
mail.To.Add(emailToID);
htmlString = @"<html><body>";
htmlString = htmlString + EmailBody;
htmlString = htmlString + "</body></html>";
mail.Subject = EmailSubject;
mail.Body = htmlString;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
if (SenderEmailID.ToString() != "")
{
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SenderEmailID, SenderEmailPassword);
    SmtpServer.Port = int.Parse(Port);
    if (SSL == "1")
    {
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    }
    else
    {
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    }
}

else
{
    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
}
try
{
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    CtlCommon.CreateErrorLog("GenerateEmail ", "Sent Succesfully");
}
```

if i set ssl as true i am getting below errors

> failure Sending Email the client and server cannot communicate because they do not possess a common algorithm

and if i use ssl as false and try to use my credentials i am getting below errors

> the smtp server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated 5.7.57

Client wants to send email without credentials

Comment: *Client wants to send email without credentials* isn't going to happen in the modern age of spam and malware.

Comment: we are sending the same on other server, also i want to use default credentials i have tried multiple ways i.e with credentials , without credentials and mentioned errors for both sections